# grafana Could not connect to given url

Tags: monitoring, grafana, zabbix

My environment

- Zabbix 3.4
- Grafana 5.2
- Grafana Zabbix Plugin 3.9.1

I have a problem about zabbix / grafana integrate test.
When input zabbix url's in grafana datasource, return "Could not connect to given url" Error.

But JSON_RPC Curl Test Return / Zabbix_DB(MySQL) Connection test OK.

Data Source for Zabbix_Monitoring:

[image]

Data Source for Zabbix_Monitoring_DB:

[image]

JSON_RPC+TEST:

[image]

Comment: Check browser console. There can be a CORS issue, https/http issue, ... Also, pls provide details how is Zabbix API url configured in the Grafana - direct or server access?

Answer (score 1):

[image: example]

if there is no connection to Zabbix, you can change the path to api_jsonrpc.php. Remove the intermediate folder out of the path (highlighted in red in the picture)

Answer (score -1):

I fix the problem by enabling the firewall and simply by command `sudo ufw allow 3000`, I opened port 3000 and problem solved.